# List of ascii ordinals to string with python

Tags: python, string, list

I've got a list of ascii ordinals like:

```
[102, 114, 97, 110, 99, 101, 115, 99, 111, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
```

now I want to transform this to a string removing the null characters at the end.

I've tried with

```
contenuto_tag = "".join(map(chr, backdata))
```

but when I pass it to a function like:

```
enos.system("php ../trigger_RFID.php %s"%(contenuto_tag))
```

I've got this error:

```
TypeError: must be string without null bytes, not str
```

maybe because there are the null characters at the end.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Filter out the null bytes first (Python 2 version):

```
>>> a = [102, 114, 97, 110, 99, 101, 115, 99, 111, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
>>> str(bytearray(filter(None, a)))
'francesco'
```

Alternative way to do it:

```
>>> ''.join(map(chr, filter(None, a)))
'francesco'
```

Some timings:

```
In [13]: a = a*1000    
In [14]: timeit ''.join(chr(i) for i in a if i)
1000 loops, best of 3: 1.44 ms per loop    
In [15]: timeit str(bytearray(filter(None, a)))
1000 loops, best of 3: 259 µs per loop    
In [16]: timeit ''.join(map(chr, filter(None, a)))
1000 loops, best of 3: 911 µs per loop
```

edit:

The `bytearray` approach that works on both Python 2/3 versions looks like this:

```
>>> bytearray(filter(None, a)).decode('ascii')
'francesco'
```

Comment: I've used your second solution. Thanks!

Comment: @DomenicoCatino no problem. I've added some timings for the three solutions you got.

Comment: @timgeb...is this Python2 or 3?

Comment: @timgeb...just because I've tried `str(bytearray(filter(None, a)))` in Python3 and it gives me `"bytearray(b'francesco')"` ..

Comment: @IronFist In Python3, `bytearray(filter(None, a)).decode('ascii')` would work.

Comment: Actually, this would work in both versions (giving you a unicode string in both).

Answer (score 6):

Use a comprehension instead and only do your `chr` on non 0:

```
a = [102, 114, 97, 110, 99, 101, 115, 99, 111, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]

b = ''.join(chr(i) for i in a if i)

print(b) # outputs francesco
```

Answer (score 0):

In Python 3, to convert a list of ascii ordinals to a bytestring, you could [use `bytes` constructor directly](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#bytes):

```
>>> a = [102, 114, 97, 110, 99, 101, 115, 99, 111, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
>>> bytes(a)
b'francesco\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00'
```

To remove trailing zero bytes, you could call [`.rstrip(b'\0')`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#bytes.rstrip):

```
>>> bytes(a).rstrip(b'\0')
b'francesco'
```

If the input should stop at the first zero byte (like C strings -- NUL terminated):

```
>>> import ctypes
>>> ctypes.create_string_buffer(bytes(b)).value
b'francesco'
```

To remove all zero bytes (wherever they are), call [`.replace()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#bytes.replace):

```
>>> bytes(a).replace(b'\0', b'')
b'francesco'
```

To get a Unicode string, call [`.decode('ascii')`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#bytes.decode):

```
>>> bytes(a).rstrip(b'\0').decode('ascii')
'francesco'
```

To make it work on both Python 2 and 3, [use `bytearray()` instead `bytes()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#binary-sequence-types-bytes-bytearray-memoryview):

```
>>> bytearray(a).rstrip(b'\0').decode('ascii')
'francesco'
```

The performance of these methods is comparable or better than `bytearray(filter(None, a))` solution from [@timgeb's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35653306/4279).